# How to access wcf service hosted in SharePoint 2010

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010

How to access a wcf service hosted in SharePoint.Are there any security gotcha to be considered.
I know that when we deploy a custom service in SharePoint it takes care of security.
How can we secure the service for ex: consuming the same service from asp.net application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful to you:

http://beta.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-create-and-host-wcf-service-inside-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am not asking how to create and deploy the service.My Question is when we deploy a wcf service in SharePoint it takes care of the security which is NTLM.But When we try to access the same service from asp.net application how can we manage the security whether its accessing the data.